# How can i center a button from a component

Tags: css, reactjs

Im using React js as my language Im using display flex on the div that contains the component and justify content center align items center and on the button's css im using align items center and display flex normally if I were to put a button in the div it centers it when you give its css align items center and display flex I couldn't find how I center it.

Comment: please provide some code and show us what you have

Comment: A better explanation or example would be handy.  It seems like you're creating a new component, call it 'ComponentA' that you are centering in some parent component, call it 'ComponentB'.  What are you trying to center where, what have you tried, and what isn't working?